# Protractor hanging on IsPresent() -- Or any other Action

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am working on trying to get some end to end tests implemented for an AngularJS site, and I am having a bit of an issue getting past a call to the IsPresent() method on the ElementFinder returned by a call to the element method.

Sadly I am governed by rules from my employer preventing me from posting ANY of our code on StackOverflow, but essentially this is what I am doing...

```
describe('Some feature', function () {
    it('Some Scenario', function () {

        browser.get(browser.baseUrl + '/#/somePage');

        var ee = element(by.css('.test-comment'));
        expect(ee.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();

    });
});
```

If I comment out the call to the expect() method, then the test executes and passes without issue. If I leave it in, I get :

> Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page
>   after 20 seconds. Please see
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/fa q.md. The
>   following tasks were pending:
>   - $timeout: function (){n=null}

This doesn't make any sense to me - the IsPresent() method returns a promise, which is resolved by the expect method, or at least that is what I would expect to happen.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`browser.isElementPresent()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.isElementPresent) instead:

```
expect(browser.isElementPresent(ee)).toBeTruthy();
```

If you are curious about the differences, please see:

- [In protractor, browser.isElementPresent vs element.isPresent vs element.isElementPresent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019429/in-protractor-browser-iselementpresent-vs-element-ispresent-vs-element-iselemen)

---

Also, you may introduce the "presence of" explicit wait before making the expectation:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var ee = element(by.css('.test-comment'));

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(ee), 5000);
expect(ee.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: @MartinMilan okay, updated with one more option, hope this one helps.

Comment: Sadly not - still getting the same problem... I'm really beginning to suspect my environment - I mean this test is hardly rocket science...

Comment: @MartinMilan same here. Please start with reinstalling protractor from scratch. Are you using jasmine2? Which protractor version? Thanks.

Comment: I have to leave the office for a train now, but I will check both of these when I get home. Thanks for your help btw - MASSIVELY appreciated,

Comment: Protractor looks like version 2.5.1 (taken from npm list)

Comment: @MartinMilan thank you for the information. And you have `framework: "jasmine2"` configured in the protractor config, right? Could you please also try with the latest protractor 3.1.1?

Comment: The protractor framework does indeed say 'jasmine2' - I'll mention about updating protractor, but it's not my call... I am beginning to suspect that the problem is either polling calls from SignalR or the use of $timeout in the AngularJS app.  It's all very weird... Must be something we are doing - if protractor was this broken someone would have put "juliemr" against the wall by now lol...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103309/discussion-between-alecxe-and-martin-milan).

Comment: @MartinMilan valid point :) Have you tried to play around with `ignoreSynchronization` flag? (I understand that this is an angular app under test, but please try)

Comment: I've not used chat... I have used ignoreSynchronization as a temporary means of getting around the problem, but I've been tasked with other tests that have taken priority. THanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

`.isDisplayed()` might be of help to you as well.

See [What is the difference between the isPresent and isDisplayed methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119084/what-is-the-difference-between-the-ispresent-and-isdisplayed-methods) for more info.

Comment: If an element is failing an isPresent() check then it cant/wont pass an isDisplayed() check.