# Getting the following error " WebDriverError: unknown error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function"

Tags: protractor

When I tried to enter a text in the below input field I am getting the error although it displayed in the window. The following input element html code is given below. I couldn't understand the reason for the error and unable to find the solution " WebDriverError: unknown error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function"

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.tag.name" ng-if="$ctrl.isSelectedMode" autofocus="autofocus" ng-blur="$ctrl.saveTagName()" name="tagName" ng-keyup="$ctrl.escapeEditing($event)" form-validator="$ctrl.tagName.uniqueError.validator" class="ng-valid ng-valid-uniqueness ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" autocomplete="off" style="">
```

I have written code in Page Object Model

```
 this.AddTag = function(tagname1,tagname2,tagname3){
           let clickAddTag = element(by.xpath("//*[text()='Add Tag']"));
           clickAddTag.click();
           browser.sleep(2000);
           let AddTag = element(by.xpath("//input[@name='tagName']"));
           if(AddTag.isPresent()){
           AddTag.sendKeys(tagname1);
           AddTag.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
           clickAddTag.click();
           AddTag.sendKeys(tagname2);
           AddTag.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
           clickAddTag.click();
           AddTag.sendKeys(tagname3);
           AddTag.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
           }
```

In specs I am calling the method 
BidConfiguration.AddTag('tag1','tag2','tag3');

Comment: I don't see `toUpperCase` anywhere in the code posted

Comment: yes. I didn't use toUpperCase function in my code but it throws the error

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to uppercase not  string but HTML element.

more less stg like that:

```
element(by.xpath("//*[text()='Add Tag']")).toUpperCase();
```

You probably want to change **text of the element** to uppercase.
Try:

```
    element(by.xpath("//*[text()='Add Tag']")).getText().then((elementText) => {
        console.log(elementText.toUpperCase());
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have problem in this element : let AddTag = element(by.xpath("//input[@name='tagName']")); and it throws the error when the I am trying to send the text using sendKeys. the element(by.xpath("//*[text()='Add Tag']")) is a button and it works fine

Comment: In `if` statement you are checking is element present. See the difference between isPresent and isDisplayed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28120175/6331748

Comment: Another thing, isPresent returns `Promise<boolean>` not just a `boolean` . http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.isPresent

Comment: Thanks Kacper it solved my problem. I just removed isPresent() and instead of sendKeys I am using browser.executeScript and now it's working

Comment: @vuppuluriatchyutharamadixit I'm facing the same issue, and i have tried `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + inputText +"')", locator);` but doesn't work. Could you please let us know any other way?

Comment: @Renu, please use the actions class which is provided below

browser.actions.click(element).sendKeys('text').perform();

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution 
use actions class with sendKeys

```
browser.actions.click(element).sendKeys('text').perform();
```

Comment: I tried the same. but throws error, browser.actions.click is not a function